# How to combine multiple GeoGraphics with custom spacing

Tags: geographics

I have a `GeoGraphics` image with some countries drawn:

```
(* countries to plot *)
countries = {
  Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
  Entity["Country", "China"],
  Entity["Country", "Japan"],
  Entity["Country", "SouthKorea"],
  Entity["Country", "UnitedKingdom"],
  Entity["Country", "Australia"]
  }

(* colours to use *)
colours  = {Red, Blue, Green, Black, Orange, Brown}

(* draw plot *)
GeoGraphics[
 MapThread[{GeoStyling[#1], 
    EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0]], 
    Polygon[#2]} &, {colours, countries}], 
GeoBackground -> White, 
ImageSize -> Large, 
GeoProjection -> "Mercator", 
GeoRangePadding -> None
]
```

[image]

**Q: How could I plot these same polygons with custom positioning, rather than with their positioning reflecting their respective geographic locations?**

I imagine this would involve plotting them separately and then cleverly combining them. I have tried with `Show[]`, but this of course aligns the plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `TranslationTransform` as an example:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], Opacity[0.3]
  , Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]["Polygon"]
  , EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Lighter@Cyan], Opacity[0.3]
  , GeometricTransformation[
   Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]["Polygon"]
   , TranslationTransform[{20, -10}]]}
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Other transforms are also available.

Comment: Thanks for this, just by playing around with `TranslationTransform[]` I'm basically able to get what I want. Do I lose the features and flexibility of `GeoGraphics[]` with these polygons by doing this method? For example, changing between types of projections (mercator vs equirectangular)?

Comment: Please read the documentation under `Details` on the `GeoGraphics` page where it talks about the differences and additions to the standard `Graphics` functionality. I cannot readily think of a way to have different projections with `Graphics` but there may be a clever workaround.

Comment: Many thanks for your help regardless, the projections point is a separate problem.